# IndexError when reading the first word in a line of a text file

Tags: python, list, filehandle

I am trying to iterate over the lines in a text file, and want only the lines that start with `"From"`.

If I split the line into a list and check the zero index, I get the first line (that starts with `"From"`), but then I get a **IndexError: list index out of range**.

When I didn't `split` the string and just used a `line.startswith("From")` method it worked.

```py
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")

try:
  fhandle = open(f"./src/{file_name}", "r")
except:
  print("file open err")
  quit()

for line in fhandle:
  line = line.strip()
  words = line.split()

  # IndexError
  if words[0] == "From": print(line)

  # This works
  if line.startswith("From"): print(line)

fhandle.close()
```

Comment: What are the typical contents of the files you try out? Do any of them have blank lines in them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide the entire stacktrace and a sample of the file which includes, at least, the first line.

Comment: @quamrana yes, okay I think I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work-

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    res = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip().startswith('From')]
```

This will give you a list of the lines that starts with **From**.